# Visual Studio find references of service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution which contains a few WCF services and one web project which consumes the services as Service References.

Now when I am in one of the services and I want to get all usages of a method then I click on the method name and perform "Find usages" or "Find references", but they do not point me to the usages in my web project. It will, however, point me to the generated Reference.cs.

I know that this is, in a way, correct behavior. But what I want is that Visual Studio or Resharper show me all the usages, even if it is the usage of the generated stubs.

Is this somehow possible with Visual Studio with Resharper or CodeRush? Is there another plugin that can provide this functionality?

Comment: *even if it is the usage of the generated stubs.* If they're all in the same solution then use channel factories with the service contract. No proxies needed and it will show usages just fine.

Comment: If you reuse types in service references you can track data contracts usage.

Comment: Well, you could use Find in Files by pressing `CTRL-SHIFT-F` and get over with it. Make sure you select `Entire Solution` in the `Look In` field.